# Question on applying L'Hopital's rule--Calculus I

Tags: calculus

In the below picture, how does the equality sign work out?

It seems that using L'Hopital's rule, the x on the bottom turns to 1, and the derivative of the expression on the numerator side is equal to the expression on the right-handed side, but I don't see how..

This is from the article: https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/10/9/380

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please accept ✓ and upvote if you want to. Otherwise feel free to ask for clarification in comments below the answer.

Comment: I apologize for getting back to you so late. Thank you so much for the answer--the question I asked puzzled me for some time, but your answer made everything clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_kc_k^x}{x}
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\left(\ln\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_kc_k^x\right)'_x}{(x)'_x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_kc_k^x\ln c_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_kc_k^x}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k\ln c_k}{\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k}_{=1}}.\\
\end{align}$$